# Calling a stored procedure which returns a sorted data from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 with a stored procedure which returns a sorted resultset (the select query with an order by). Can I be sure that the returned ObjectResult will be sorted the same way in terms of passing through the foreach loop?

Comment: I tried executing my SP and results seems to be correct (in the right order), but I am not 100% sure that this is a general rule as many factors can have influence on sorting (like currently I do sorting on the PK field, what if I will sort by non PK field, etc.).

Comment: As records order is important to me and I don't know ObjectResult population internals I moved sorting from SP to .net code like this: ObjectResult<T>.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.Value).ToList()